# MaxRequestBodySize not working in webserver with Azure App Service

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

MaxRequestBodySize is not working when its deployed to webserver with Azure App Service but it works in my local. I tried with the below changes in program.cs and startup.cs of my .net core 3.1 but none of them worked. Still getting 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error.

```
Program.cs:
1. webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                       {
                           serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
                       })


2. .UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
}

Startup.cs
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 11):

Go to the kudu console of your web app (https://{your-website-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/). Click on **Debug Console** dropdown in the menu and choose **CMD**.
You will see your web app directory structure listed below. Use the list interface to navigate to **site > wwwroot**. Scroll down to the bottom till you come across the **web.config** file. Click on the edit icon on the left of the file which will open the file in an editor.
Add the following lines under <system.webServer>:

```
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"  />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

This sets the maximum request length to 4 GB. Close the kudu console and restart your application from azure portal. Then try again.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me alot. Is there a way to edit the web.config during publish process?