# dotnet6 on Azure WebApp - http error 413 request entity too large

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, http-status-code-413

I'm getting the following error while uploading large (38 MB) file using file upload on .NET 6 application deployed on Azure using Chrome browser:

[image]

I googled and found 2 solutions. It works fine in my local environment but not working after I deployed it to Azure.

Solution 1: In `Program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
});
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
});
```

Solution 2: `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` file

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
            });
```

Comment: what type of azure service ? webapp / function app / aks / others?

Comment: @Thomas - webapp

Comment: have tou check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641344/4167200

Comment: @Thomas - I have .Net6 application and It doesn't have web.config file in the solution. Will the above mentioned solution work in this scenario on azure? I am new to azure so not sure whether I can have web.config file on azure or not for .Net6 application. Please suggest.

Comment: this was an answer with dotnet core without webconfig so i would assume it would work

Comment: is it running on windows or linux plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with large files, we need to make sure the `maxAllowedContentLength` and `maxRequestLength` is set correctly according to the request and file size in `Web.config` file.

*****`maxRequestLength` in `<system.web>`:*****

```cs
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824"/>
</system.web>
```

Thanks @Thomas for the comments

***`maxAllowedContentLength` in security section***

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#configuration), Add `maxAllowedContentLength` in the security tag.

```cs
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Thanks @[bhawanisingh] for clear steps.

Refer this [blog](https://hoststud.com/resources/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-file-size-in-iis.422/)  for more details on how to work with large files.

> I have .Net6 application and It doesn't have web.config file in the solution

When you deploy `.Net Core App` to Azure App Service (Windows / Linux),`web.config` file be generated automatically in the deployed files (with basic settings).

***Windows:***
[image]

***Linux:***
[image]

You can even add the `web.config` file locally in the application root directory and deploy along with other files.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. Thanks for sharing this answer.